# docker-compose throwing a TypeEroor for a basic example on windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've tried [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) basic docker-compose example and it throws the following error:

```
Building web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 127, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1085, in up
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 1081, in up
  File "compose\project.py", line 527, in up
  File "compose\service.py", line 360, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose\service.py", line 1084, in build
  File "site-packages\docker\api\build.py", line 147, in build
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
[6636] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

In my testing directory I have 4 files:
app.py:

```py
import time

import redis
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)


def get_hit_count():
    retries = 5
    while True:
        try:
            return cache.incr('hits')
        except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
            if retries == 0:
                raise exc
            retries -= 1
            time.sleep(0.5)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    count = get_hit_count()
    return 'Hello World! I have been seen {} times.\n'.format(count)
```

requirements.txt:

```
flask
redis
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

From powershell, in the directory with all these files I run: `docker-compose up`.

I've tried: `docker build .` and it builds the dockerfile as expected.

I've tried the exact same code on my mac, and it works just fine.

If I remove the `web` section from docker-file, it builds the redis service just fine.

If I build the Dockerfile separately then link the built image in the docker-compose file, then it works:

```
web:
    image: 5565302e34cd
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Reading through some similar questions, I have also tried the following code, but I get the same error:

```
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

I'm on windows 10 Pro, 8 RAM.

```
docker -v
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89

docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

Please, I need help. I started to get crazy.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this problem and I can't get it working...

Answer (score -1):

You can modify docker-compose file like this.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
redis:
  image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: Thats weird, its appearing on windows only.

Comment: can you place "dockerfile: Dockerfile" after build context

Comment: in my question, I described how I tried that as well.